# ex20 Python understanding

Tags: python

The text below is from the LPTHW and I have a question about the variables age, height ETC.

I just want to confirm that I understand this correctly, but when writing a variable, it appears to also be calling the function. IE for age it is printing "ADDING 30 + 5". Is this correct or am i missing something?

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    print "DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b


print "Let's do some math with just functions!"

age = add(30, 5)
height = subtract(78, 4)
weight = multiply(90, 2)
iq = divide(100, 2)

print "Age: %d, Height: %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)
```

Comment: `age = add(30, 5)` assigns the returned value from func `add` it would've printed the same statement with the line `add(30, 5)`

Answer (score 2):

The function is being called before the variable is written. Whenever you do:

```
height = subtract(78, 4)
```

First, the `subtract` function is called with two parameters, 78 and 4. Inside the function, the message is printed. When it finishes, the returned value is essentially assigned to `height`.